# Extract header from each sheet of an excel file and save it in a dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Read all excel sheets and extract first row of each sheet and save it as a dataframe , through pandas! I want to extract the first row of each sheet in an excel file, and save it in a dataframe.

This is what I am trying, how do i move ahead?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
input_excel = pd.ExcelFile("f1.xlsx")

for sheet in input_excel.sheet_names:
    input_sheet = input_excel.parse(sheet, headers=True)
    df.append(input_sheet)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is for each sheetname same number of columns (first row) use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with `sheet_name=None` for all sheetname to DataFrames - dictioanry of DataFrames and then parse columns to list, last pass to `DataFrame`:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx", sheet_name=None)

cols = [df.columns for i, df in dfs.items()]
print (cols)
[Index(['a', 'e'], dtype='object'), Index(['u', 't'], dtype='object'), 
 Index(['i', 'p'], dtype='object')]

df = pd.DataFrame(cols)
print (df)
   0  1
0  a  e
1  u  t
2  i  p
```

If there is different number of columns one possible idea:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel("files/a.xlsx", sheet_name=None)

print ([df.columns for i, df in dfs.items()])
[Index(['a', 'e'], dtype='object'), Index(['u', 't'], dtype='object'),
 Index(['i', 'p', 'd', 'f'], dtype='object')]

cols = [(x, i) for i, df in dfs.items() for x in df.columns]
print (cols)
[('a', 'Sheet1'), ('e', 'Sheet1'), ('u', 'Sheet2'), ('t', 'Sheet2'), 
 ('i', 'Sheet3'), ('p', 'Sheet3'), ('d', 'Sheet3'), ('f', 'Sheet3')]

df = pd.DataFrame(cols)
print (df)
   0       1
0  a  Sheet1
1  e  Sheet1
2  u  Sheet2
3  t  Sheet2
4  i  Sheet3
5  p  Sheet3
6  d  Sheet3
7  f  Sheet3
```

Comment: Your first solution worked perfectly!Just basic pre processing was needed thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use `pd.read_excel` ([link here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)), as following:

```py
xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
my_excel = pd.read_excel(xls, your_sheet_name = None)

for pos,val in enumerate(my_excel.keys()):
    if pos == 0:
        my_df = my_excel[val].iloc[0,:]
    else:
        my_df = my_df.append(my_excel[val].iloc[0,:])
```

This is not a pretty solution, but should work.